# Code assist for Python on xCode

Tags: python, xcode

Is there a way to get code assist (code completion) to work with Python on xCode?

In other words, when I start typing eat_food(, I want xCode to tell me what the first argument for the function "eat_food" is so I won't have to search my project for the function signature.

Comment: A big list of Python IDEs is in this famous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python and all other dynamic languages are notoriously hard to write comprehensive code completion for. The compiler doesn't even know what types and other things about dynamic code, so the IDE isn't going to either. [Komodo](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit) does one of the best jobs at code completion for dynamic languages like Python, but even it isn't anywhere 100%, not even the IDE version.

Apple is actively discouraging all languages other than what they consider first class languages for OSX/iOS Objective-C, Swift, C and C++ in Xcode. I wouldn't expect much support for any other languages since they dropped Java support, which was incredibly crappy anyway.